# vue.js empty POST to flask server

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, flask

I have a flask server that servers the following jinja template on "GET /form"

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block dev_scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@latest/lodash.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block prod_scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@latest/lodash.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block contents %}
    <div class="container" id="app">
        {{ errors }}
        <form></form>
    </div>

    <template id="Form-template">
        <form id="myform" class="row border-between" @submit="checkForm" method="post">
            ...
        </form>
    </template>

    <script>
        Vue.options.delimiters = ['[[', ']]'];
        Vue.component('form', {
            name: 'Form',
            template: '#Form-template',
            data() {
                return {
                    data1: {
                        item1: '',
                        item2: '',
                    },
                    data2: {
                        item1: '',
                        item2: '',
                    },
                    method: '',
                    errors: {},
                };
            },
            methods: {
                checkForm(e) {
                    this.errors = {};

                    if (e.submitter.id === 'data1-submit') {
                        this.$data.method = 'data1';

                        if (this.data1.item1 && this.data1.item2) return true;

                        if (!this.data1.item1) {
                            this.errors = _.merge({ data1: { item1: 'item1 required' } }, this.errors);
                        }

                        if (!this.data1.item2) {
                            this.errors = _.merge({ data1: { item2: 'item2 required' } }, this.errors);
                        }
                    }
                    ...

                    e.preventDefault();
                },
            },
        });
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Upon form submission, a "POST /form" is generated but no data is included in the POST.

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form)
        print(request.json)
        print(request.data)
```

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
None
b''
```

I have tried to use `axios.post(window.location.href, this.$data);` but I can't then redirect the user as the browser itself isn't making the POST request.

Is there any way to allow the browser to make the POST request, as above, while still including the data from the vue component?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Python / Flask, but you might be missing the content type?
And you could also redirect to preferred url after the response comes back.

Something like this:

```
const url = window.location.href;
const data = this.$data;
const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

const response = axios.post(url, data, headers);

if (!response) return false;

window.location.href = enter-preferred-redirect-url-here;
```